# WordPress child, grandchild, great grandchild categories must use parent category template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, categories, parent

I have created a template named category-south-africa.php. I would like all child, grandchild, great grandchild categories to automatically use this template. For example, all these categories must use the category-south-africa.php template:

```
/category/south-africa/
/category/south-africa/stellenbosch/
/category/south-africa/stellenbosch/wine-farm/
/category/south-africa/stellenbosch/wine-farm/wine-varietal/
```

Does anyone perhaps have a php function solution?

Comment: There will be additional country categories that need to work in the same way. E.g category-france.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create you own template for this. You can check the `category_template` filter and do something like this.

```
add_filter('category_template', 'add_top_term_template');
function add_top_term_template($template) {
    $term = get_queried_object();
    $parent = $term->parent;

    if($parent === 0) {
        return $template;
    }
    $topLevel = null;
    while($parent !== 0) {
        $topLevel = get_term($parent);
        $parent = $topLevel->parent;
    }

    $templates = ["term-top-level-{$topLevel->slug}.php"];
    
    return locate_template($templates);
}
```

You can find more info about the filter here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/category_template

Comment: Thanks for this. This line was flagged in my editor:
$templates = ["term-top-level-{$topLevel->slug}.php"];
I changed "term-top-level" to my template name. I don't know php very well.

Comment: @Arra i updated the code. You can try now. I had forgotten to add ; on the return. Also what version of php are you using? If you use < 5.4 you can change the ["term-top-level-{$topLevel->slug}.php"] with array("term-top-level-{$topLevel->slug}.php"). Also leave the template as name as it is, this will let you reuse the code for other categories. Now if you create a template file with the name like term-top-level-south-africa.php All children of south-africa will use this template

Comment: And if you need for example europe you can just create term-top-level-europe.php and all children of europe will use the new tempalte.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm using php version 7.1. I tried your code as is, but unfortunately the child category doesn't use the parent template

Comment: Did you create a file called term-top-level-south-africa.php?

Comment: I did not, but I have now. It works brilliantly! Thank you very much! Apologies for not following your instructions initially. The parent category still needs category-south-africa.php, but I'm OK with that.

Answer (score 0):

get_ancestors() that returns an array containing the parents of any given category.

use like get_ancestors( child_category_id, 'category' );

Check the value is in the array or not. if yes then define template name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know css and html but don't know php very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function to check if the current category is a child category and set the template to the same you have for the parent category. Put this in the functions.php of your theme.

```
function childcategory_template( $template ) {
    $cat = get_queried_object();
    if( 0 < $cat->category_parent )
        $template = locate_template( 'category-south-africa.php');
    return $template;
    }
    add_filter( 'category_template', 'childcategory_template' );
```

---

**Edit after comment:** You can also check the name (slug) and set the $template variable taking the name (slug) of the parent into account.

```
function childcategory_template( $template ) {
    $cat = get_queried_object();
    if( 0 < $cat->category_parent )
        $parent_id = $cat->category_parent;
        if ( get_category( $parent_id )->slug == "south-africa" ) {
            $template = locate_template( 'category-south-africa.php');
        } else if ( get_category( $parent_id )->slug == "north-africa" ) {
            $template = locate_template( 'category-north-africa.php');
        }
    return $template;
    }
    add_filter( 'category_template', 'childcategory_template' );
```

Comment: Hi Rank. Thanks for this. I tried it. This function makes all child categories use the template category-south-africa, even for other child categories that are not children of category-south-africa. Any ideas? I appreciate your help. I also need to duplicate this function for other country categories

Comment: I added a way to check the slug of the category and set different templates for different slugs. I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks! This works very well for the different parent categories and their respective child categories. Is there a way to get the grandchild and great grandchild categories to also use the parent template?